# C#.NET How to replace an user control from other user control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a **MainForm** and 3 user control. In my main form, I've loaded **UserControl_1** in **Panel_1** when press a button. My **UserControl_1** have 2 other buttons. If I press **UserControl_1->Button_1** , then **UserControl_2** will load at **MainForm's Panel_1** and **UserControl_1** will disposed.

[image: Main Form]

[image: User Control 1]

How to do this ..??

Comment: What have you tried ? I suggest your user control 1 having a routed event that gets raised when its button1 is pressed. Your main form will have a handler for this event and will then be able to do whatever's necessary.

Comment: They are *not* called 'form's in WPF... using that terminology here is confusing as it makes one think of WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to have one UI control that displays the different `UserControl`s. To make this work, you need to do a few things.

a) Create a `BaseViewModel` class that implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

b) Create a `...ViewModel` class that extends the `BaseViewModel` class *for each* `UserControl`.

c) Declare a `DataTemplate` *for each* `...ViewModel`/`UserControl` pair in `App.xaml`... it should be something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourViewModelsPrefix:SomeViewModel}">
    <YourViewsPrefix:SomeView />
</DataTemplate>
```

d) Create a property in the object that is set as the `DataContext` for `MainWindow.xaml` of type `BaseViewModel`... let's name it `ViewModel` for the purposes of this example.

e) Add a `ContentControl` to the XAML in `MainWindow.xaml` wherever you want the `UserControl`s to appear:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

f) Finally, set that property to any of the derived `...ViewModel` classes:

```
ViewModel = new SomeViewModel();
```

The Framework will then search for a `DataTemplate` for the `SomeViewModel` type, find your one defined in `App.xaml`, render the view model according to that template and therefore display your `UserControl`. To change the view model, just set the `ViewModel` property to another of the derived `...ViewModel` classes:

```
ViewModel = new AnotherViewModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContentPresenter to show your user control in the main form. This content presenter will depend on the state in your view model. After clicking a button in any of your user controls you can change the state property and the ContentPresenter will substitute the current user control with a new one.

For example:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentPresenter.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="State1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <settingsview:UserControl1 />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="State2">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <settingsview:UserControl2 />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="State3">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <settingsview:UserControl3 />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentPresenter.Style>
</ContentPresenter>
```